# Docking station with new Interfaces?

Tags: usb, hdmi, docking-stations, thunderbolt, ethernet

I think we all noticed the recent Intel Skylake release at IFA and Gamescom 2015.

Skylake brought a new generation of processor supporting a new generation of I/O interfaces, mainly Thunderbolt 3.

As I'm planning to get a Laptop with Thunderbolt 3 very soon I'm looking for a docking station for said laptop.

The station should connect with my laptop via Thunderbolt 3 (preferably) or via USB 3.1 (type C). If there's absolutely nothing supporting Thunderbolt 3 or USB 3.1 (C) USB 3.0 (type A) is also acceptable.

It should feature at least 4x USB 2.0, 4x USB 3.0 (both type A), a HDMI interface and a gigabit ethernet interface. Ideally it would also feature USB 3.1 type C or Thunderbolt 3 ports and / or display port(s).

Comment: Is there any company which you are interested in?

Comment: @belford, no I don't have any preferences concerning brands / companies as long as they are somewhat relieable.

Answer (score 5):

Due to the fact that this is novelty on the market, it would be not that easy to find exacly what you want but **[Elgato Thunderbolt Dock](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IM3OZ1C)** is relatively close. We can expect that they will release similar model with **Thunderbolt 3**.

1. Two Thunderbolt 2 ports
2. Built-in HDMI port
3. Built-in Gigabit Ethernet
4. Three USB 3.0 ports

[image: Elgato Dock - Front]

[image: Elgato Dock - Back]

Comment: *"Three USB 3.0 ports"* isn't bad, bad I was asking for 4x 2.0 + 4x 3.0 (-> 8x USB) so it'd require me to buy another hub :( but nice pictures though :) And nice that it already has thunderbolt (although 2) :) May I ask what is the usual way to connect this dock to your laptop? USB? Thunderbolt? "Whatever you want"?

Comment: Thunderbolt: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Y21dgDHsq0