# Docking station with many ports?

Tags: usb, hdmi, ethernet, docking-stations

[I've "recentely" asked this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/188/273) here for a docking station for laptops that uses Thunderbolt 3 or USB 3.1 for connections. While I'm still interested in such stations I need an alternative in case no such alternative will be available within a reasonable time-frame.

So I'm hereby asking for a docking station that qualifies with the following points (in order of preference):

- It connects via USB 3.0 and doesn't require special additional software for Windows (10) besides maybe a driver
- It has at least 4 USB 3.0 ports (additionally to the connecting port)
- It has at least 4 other USB (2.0+) ports (so 8 ports in total)
- It has a gigabit ethernet network port
- It has a HDMI (1.4+) port for monitor output
- It has yet another 2 USB (2.0+) ports (so 10 in total)
- Price should be less than 200€ (in [Germany](http://www.amazon.de/))
- Fully optional: Smartcard Reader

If you ask yourself: "For what do you *need* 8 (or more) USB ports for a laptop!?" Here's the list: External USB 3.0 SSD, External 2.5" USB 3.0 HDD, External 3.5" USB 3.0 Backup HDD, High-Speed USB 3.0 USB-Stick, external USB 2.0 sound card, external mechanical USB keyboard, external USB mouse, external blu-ray burner (2x USB 2.0)

Please note: all of these devices are already bought and may not be deconstructed, so a dock with HDD bay or optical drive (bay) doesn't give "bonus points".

Comment: What about mixing external usb hub and docking station? It'd be pretty easy to find external usb 3.0 hub with 8 slots http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/341/cheap-usb3-0-hub/345#345

Comment: @belford, I'd prefer not having to use external hubs as well, because this will result in a mess with the power supply cables (the 3.5" needs external power, the dock needs power and the hub would need power as well). I'm asking this to find a solution that doesn't two-level require additional hardware. If there's no such hardware, I guess I just get the recommended hub and the [toshiba dock](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B006ZGWJU2?keywords=dynadock%20u3&qid=1444509634&ref_=sr_1_1&sr=8-1).

Comment: Check this one (or suggestions by amazon) http://www.amazon.com/Woopower%C2%AEWPUL02-Superspeed-Universal-Ethernet-Microphone/dp/B012D05QY4/

Comment: I was trying to find information about these ports (sometimes the red one has only the charge wires connected). However, you have one external  2.5" hdd support. Would it be useful for you? Check also: http://superuser.com/questions/70662/why-does-my-usb-cable-have-an-extra-red-plug and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Colors

Comment: @belford, I don't think this helps as I really don't want to deconstruct my external HDD :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30115/discussion-between-belford-and-sejpm).

Answer (score 2):

Note: Typical docking station has 2-4 USB ports, sometimes 5-6.

**Option 1**

[Cable Matters® SuperSpeed USB 3.0 Universal Docking Station with 6-Port USB Hub](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00H2WBXQO)

Score:

1. (✓) Connection:one cable to the USB 3.0/2.0 port of your computer.
2. (✓) it has 6 USB 3.0 ports (additionally to the connecting port)
3. (X) it hasn't USB 2.0 ports
4. (✓) Gigabit Ethernet
5. (✓) HDMI (resolutions: up to 2048x1152/1920x1200)
6. (X) the same as 3.
7. (✓) $89.99 and this item ships to Germany

Optional:

8. (X) It hasn't Smartcard Reader

**Option 2**

[Woopower WPUL02](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B012D05QY4) has 4 USB 3.0 + 2 USB 2.0 + 2 USB charger port.

Does the red one has only the charge wires connected? Yes, probably. There's no clear statement in the description.
What is more...

Based on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Colors):

> USB ports and connectors are often color-coded to distinguish their
>   different functions and USB versions. These colors are not part of the
>   USB specification and can vary between manufacturers; for example, USB 3.0 
>   specification mandates appropriate color-coding
>   while it only recommends blue inserts for standard-A USB 3.0
>   connectors and plugs

Score:

1. (✓) Connection:one cable to the USB 3.0/2.0 port of your computer.
2. (✓) it has 4 USB 3.0 ports (additionally to the connecting port)
3. (X) it has just 2 USB 2.0 ports
4. (✓) Gigabit Ethernet
5. (✓) HDMI (display resolution up to 2048 x 1152)
6. (X) the same as 3.
7. (✓) $105€ and this item ships to Germany

Optional:

8. (X) It hasn't Smartcard Reader